# How are Java generic parameters inferred?

Tags: java

Example1:

```java
List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(2, 3.14, "four");
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
Collections.copy(objs, ints);
```

Example2:

```java
List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(2, 3.14, "four");
List<? extends Number> ints = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
Collections.copy(objs, ints);
```

This is Collections copy method(part of it) :

```java
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
   for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
     dst.set(i, src.get(i));
   }
}
```

In Example1, Collections copy method's generic parameter T can be： Integer, Number, Object. So which one will the compiler infer? why?

In Example2, Collections copy method's generic parameter T can be： Number, Object. So which one will the compiler infer? why?

thanks!

Comment: Probably 1: `Integer` and 2: `Number` since those are the most specific matching types.

Comment: In a weird way it does not matter: Since the type parameter is not reified (i.e. it has no real representation at runtime) the only thing that matters is **if** the compiler can infer a type that fits all constraints and not so much *what* type it infers. Can you give a specific example where you think it would matter?

Comment: The Java Language Specification has [an entire chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-18.html) on type inference.  Read it if you dare.  Normally I enjoy reading the concise rules of the JLS, but this section has parts which are complex enough to make my head swim.

Comment: @VGR: yes, it's one of the trickier ones and that even applies to compiler writes. I remember that many of the differences that I saw between the Eclipse compiler and the JDK one were related to this area (and in at least one of those cases the Eclipse compiler got it right first and the JDK compilers behaviour was actually a bug according to the spec).